# VHDL Same name declaration

Tags: vhdl

I am such a newer in VHDL, I have simple questions.

What is the "width" for VHDL's bit vector?

For example, x"1101" : width = 4?

And Can I give same name to signal and variable?

For example,

```
signal SameNAME : std_logic;
variable SameNAME : std_logic; 
signal SameName : std_logic_vector;
```

is it legal?

Thank you.

Comment: VHDL is case insensitive.

Comment: `x"1101"` has 16 bits because you are using a hexadecimal literal.

Answer (score 0):

> **What is the "width" for VHDL's bit vector?**
>
> For example, x"1101" : width = 4?

The proper term for the expression is a bit string literal.

A bit string literal that has an equivalent string literal value by expanding the base 16 digits to their equivalent See IEEE Std 1076-2008, 15.8 Bit string literals, the table in para 6, and para 5:

> A bit string literal has a value that is a string literal. The string literal is formed from the bit value by first obtaining a *simplified bit value*, consisting of the bit value with underline characters removed, and then obtaining an *expanded bit value*. Finally, the string literal value is obtained by adjusting the expanded bit value, if required.
>
> If the base specifier is B, UB or SB, the expanded bit value is the simplified bit value itself. If the base specifier is O, UO, or SO (respectively X, UX, or SX), the expanded bit value is the string obtained by replacing each character of the simplified bit value by a sequence of three (respectively four) characters. For a character in the simplified bit value that is interpreted as an extended digit, the replacement sequence is as follows:
>
> [image: substitution table]
>   For a character in the simplified value that is not interpreted as an extended digit, each character in the replacement sequence is the same as the character replaced.

If you expand the bit string literal to the equivalent string value it would have a length of 16 which can be found by evaluating the 'LENGTH attribute (e.g. `someone'length`) and the resulting string value would be `"0001000100000001"`.

> **And Can I give same name to signal and variable?**
>
> For example,
>
> ```
> signal SameNAME : std_logic;
> variable SameNAME : std_logic; 
> signal SameName : std_logic_vector;
> ```
>
> is it legal?

15.4.2 Basic identifiers, para 3:

> All characters of a basic identifier are significant, including any underline character inserted between a letter or digit and an adjacent letter or digit. Basic identifiers differing only in the use of corresponding uppercase and lowercase letters are considered the same.

No. Basic dentifiers differing only in case are considered the same. If you want to distinguish by case use extended identifiers.